# adding computer name to active directory group

Tags: c#, sharepoint, workflow, workflow-activity

I have a requirement where I have to add computer name to the pre-defined active directory group. Does anyone have experience related to this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this through C# code using System.DirectoryServices

```
// Bind to the Computers container and add a new computer.
DirectoryEntry de01 = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=Computers,DC=fabrikam,DC=com");
DirectoryEntry newComputer = de01.Children.Add("CN=New Computer", "computer");
newGroup.CommitChanges();
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180832(v=VS.90).aspx for examples.

Comment: this did not work for me not sure why. it returns sucessful but computer does not get added.

Answer (score 0):

Use ADSI. Basically you bind to the Active Directory, locate the computer object and group object you need, and call a method to add the computer to the group.

If it needs to be from a command line, you can easily do this using WSH or .Net.

ADSI reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772218(v=VS.85).aspx

ADSI LDAP:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746384(v=VS.85).aspx

It will not take effect until the computer reboots.

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me

```
  //Step 1: get the DN of the adgroup you want to use
    DirectoryEntry groupEntry = new DirectoryEntry   ("LDAP://CN=AdgroupNameWewantToAddTo,DC=na,DC=ABCint,DC=com");//adgroupDSN
```

> > ```
> > //step 2: get the Dn of the pc you want to add to the group
> > string memberDN;
> > DirectorySearcher dom = new DirectorySearcher(baseDN);
> > dom.Filter = "(&(ObjectCategory=computer) (cn=" + PCNAME+ "))";
> > SearchResult searchResult = dom.FindOne();
> > if (searchResult != null)
> >  {
> >     memberDN=searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Path;
> >  }
> > ```
> >
> > //Step 3:add PC to the ad group
> >            groupEntry.Invoke("Add", computerdn);